# Google maps API loads for a second then says check js console but no warnings or errors, any ideas

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using an API in a website for the first time, the google map pops up with the marker on my location that I have set but immediately goes gray and says check the console, in which there are no errors or warnings.

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async defer>
</script>

  <script>
  function initMap() {
    var albany = {lat: 42.676762, lng: -73.821991};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: albany
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: albany,
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: The posted code works for me on jsfiddle if I add the missing HTML/CSS.  Is that key valid for wherever you are trying to run it?

Comment: I think it's good, maybe I'll create another one and try that

Comment: yup it was the API key, thats weird

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a valid key when you load the API.

The console should contain text to that effect and the URL that needs to be authorized.